# Removing rows with NA value in column

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset.csv in R. I want to remove all NA values from the Rank columns.

The column is like this

```
Rank    State
NA  District of Columbiaâ€
1   Connecticut
2   New Jersey
3   Massachusetts
4   Maryland
5   New Hampshire
6   Virginia
7   New York
8   North Dakota
9   Alaska
10  Minnesota
11  Colorado
12  Washington
13  Rhode Island
14  Delaware
15  California
16  Illinois
17  Hawaii
18  Wyoming
19  Pennsylvania
20  Vermont
NA  United States
21  Iowa
```

The dataframe of this CSV is called RacePerState

The code I have tried

```
subset(RacePerState, State!="United States" && State!="District of Columbiaâ€" && !="Puerto Ricoâ€")

RacePerState <- RacePerState[!(RacePerState$Rank=="NA"),]
```

But when i write the dataframe to a csv the data is still there.

Any help?

Comment: Read `?is.na` to get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RacePerState <- subset(RacePerState, !is.na(Rank))
```

or

```
RacePerState <- RacePerState[!is.na(RacePerState$Rank), ]
```

or

```
RacePerState <- RacePerState[complete.cases(RacePerState), ]
```

or

```
require(dplyr);
require(magrittr);
RacePerState %>% na.omit();
```